# Scroll functions all firing together in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I have made a few scroll functions with anchor tags that when the anchor reaches the top of the page, it then triggers certain animations. Super simple stuff.

But for some reason in Safari, as soon as the first anchor point is reached, they all fire at the same time. This defeats the point.

I think it may be the way I am checking for when the user scrolls, but I think someone with a bit more knowledge than me can help.

I have attached a snippet for you to look at -

CODE -

```js
//SCROLL TO TRIGGER CHARTS

$(function() {
  var oTop = $('#chartAnchor').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
  var chartHidden = true;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var pTop = $('body').scrollTop();
    if ((pTop > oTop) && (chartHidden)) {
      chartHidden = false;
      makeCharts();
    }
  });
});

//TOTAL VIEWS COUNTER FUNCTIONS

$(function() {
  var oTop = $('#stat-anchor').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
  var chartHidden = true;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var pTop = $('body').scrollTop();
    if ((pTop > oTop) && (chartHidden)) {
      chartHidden = false;
      $('.counter').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
          countTo = $this.attr('data-count');

        $({
          countNum: $this.text()
        }).animate({
            countNum: countTo
          },

          {

            duration: 1500,
            easing: 'linear',
            step: function() {
              $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
            },
            complete: function() {
              var finalNum = this.countNum.toString().replace(/(\d+)(\d{6})/, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
              finalNum = finalNum.toString().replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
              $this.text(finalNum);
              ready = false;
            }

          });

      });
    }
  });
});

//GENDERS COUNTER FUNCTIONS

$(function() {
  var oTop = $('#gender-anchor').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
  var chartHidden = true;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var pTop = $('body').scrollTop();

    if ((pTop > oTop) && (chartHidden)) {
      $('.male').addClass('left');
      $('.female').addClass('right');
      chartHidden = false;

      $('.counter2').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
          countTo = $this.attr('data-count');

        $({
          countNum: $this.text()
        }).animate({
            countNum: countTo
          },

          {

            duration: 1500,
            easing: 'linear',
            step: function() {
              $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
            },
            complete: function() {
              var finalNum = this.countNum;
              $this.text(finalNum + '%');
            }

          });

      });

      //Affinity & Age Animations

      $('.affinity-info').css('opacity', '1');
      $('.user-age').css('opacity', '1');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="view-demos" id="chartAnchor" href="mailto:adrian@hsm.co.za">Enquire for more stats</a>

<div class="mobile-stat-wrap" id="stat-anchor">
  <img class="device-icon" src="img/mobileIcon.png">
  <p class="device-icon-head">Mobile</p>
  <p id="mobile-stat" class="device-stat">7,302,872</p>
</div>
<div class="counter-wrap col-12">
  <p class="stats-heading-small">Total Views</p>
  <div class="counter" data-count="16400708">0</div>
</div>

<div class="gender-wrap">
  <div class="center-wrap">
    <p class="stats-heading-small">Gender</p>
    <div class="male">
      <img class="gender-icon" src="img/male.png">
      <p class="gender-stat counter2" id="male-stat" data-count="55">%</p>
    </div>

    <div class="female">
      <img class="gender-icon" src="img/female.png">
      <p class="gender-stat counter2" id="female-stat" data-count="45">%</p>
      <span id="gender-anchor"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="affinity-info-wrap col-12">
    <img class="affinity-info" src="img/affinityInfo.png">
    <img class="user-age" src="img/userAge.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you saying that your gender and total views counters together are firing at the same time? Is it just Safari your seeing the problem with? I ran your code in both Chrome and Safari, and they are performing how I would expect them to from reading your code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So basically. When you reach the chartAnchor, the charts animate, while the stat and gender animations stay the same. When you reach the statAnchor, the stats will then animate, but the gender animation will still be waiting until the user scrolls to the gender anchor. In chrome they run in sequence, whereas Safari triggers all of them when the chartAnchor is triggered.

Comment: I also dont think you should run the snippet in stack on safari. Because I think it has to do with the 

var pTop = $('body').scrollTop(); 

or the

var oTop = $('#chartAnchor').offset().top - window.innerHeight;

Comment: The issue is with you subtracting the window height from the anchor's top offset. If you remove it, it will let the animations fire only when the element is at the top of the page. Is there something else you are trying to accomplish by subtracting the window height?

Comment: I think you are so right! Because I'm not using the window height for anything specific, it was just a point for the anchor to trigger. Great answer, thank you for your help. Make it a answer so I can mark it correct. Thanks Nick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't subtract window height to get the location of your anchor.

```
$(function() {
  //Don't need to subtract the top offset by window innerHeight
  //var oTop = $('#gender-anchor').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
  var oTop = $('#gender-anchor').offset().top;
  var chartHidden = true;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var pTop = $('body').scrollTop();

    if ((pTop > oTop) && (chartHidden)) {
      $('.male').addClass('left');
      $('.female').addClass('right');
      chartHidden = false;

      $('.counter2').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
          countTo = $this.attr('data-count');

        $({
          countNum: $this.text()
        }).animate({
            countNum: countTo
          },

          {

            duration: 1500,
            easing: 'linear',
            step: function() {
              $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
            },
            complete: function() {
              var finalNum = this.countNum;
              $this.text(finalNum + '%');
            }

          });

      });

      //Affinity & Age Animations

      $('.affinity-info').css('opacity', '1');
      $('.user-age').css('opacity', '1');
    }
  });
});
```